# My simple "Hello World" program is not running into Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run my simple program, i added `spring framework jar files` and `common-logging jar files` too into my reference library.

Here is my first program says ***HelloWorld.java***:

```
package com.rajendra.lesson01;

public class HelloWorld {

    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message=message;
    }

    public void getMessage(){
        System.out.println("Messge: "+message);
    }
}
```

Here is my another program says ***MainProgram.java***:

```
package com.rajendra.lesson01;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        HelloWorld hw=(HelloWorld) ac.getBean("helloWorld");

        hw.getMessage();
    }
}
```

and here is my last one ***bean.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.rajendra.lesson01.HelloWorld">
    <property name="message" value="My name is foo.." />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Everything goes fine according to tutorial but my **Output** says:

```
Oct 20, 2014 9:12:19 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c12fb0: startup date [Mon Oct 20 09:12:19 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 20, 2014 9:12:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [bean.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [bean.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bean.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.rajendra.lesson01.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bean.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 13 more
```

**What's happening here please help? and also tell me how do you guys find the errors?**

Help Would be appreciated!

Comment: The xml file needs to be at the root of the classpath (with the path you are using - just the file name), i.e. (with maven) src/main/resources/beans.xml

Comment: I don't know what you're saying but here you could see my [**Image**](http://postimg.org/image/85fyp7lpb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

In this example you have to put bean.xml out of the "com.rajendra.lesson01" package ... put it in resource package.
I hope this can help you.

[image]